# django: following relationship backwards to subclass in multi-table inheritance

Tags: django, inheritance, foreign-key-relationship

I would welcome any help with my problem. I'm trying to follow a relationship backwards to a subclass in a multi-table inheritance situation.

I.e. I would like a queryset of all restaurants in a particular state.

Here is a simplified example of my question (a modification on the eg in django's documentation);

```
from django.db import models

class Place(models.Model):
    state = models.ForeignKey('State')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=80)

class Restaurant(Place):
    serves_hot_dogs = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    serves_pizza = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class State(models.Model):
    state = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

If I try `state.restaurant_set.all()` I receive an exception

> 'State' object has no attribute 'Restaurant_set'

however if I try state.place_set.all() I receive a query set of places in that state, but I really just want restaurants in the state.

Can anyone provide some suggestions on how to correctly formulate my queryset, or provide some other ideas on how to achieve this?

Any assistance will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 4):

You can't follow the foreign key backwards from `State` to `Restaurant`, but you can achieve the same result by filtering using the restaurant's inherited foreign key to state:

```
restaurants = Restaurant.objects.filter(state=state)
```

Answer (score 1):

in your `Place` model you have defined a foreign key to `State`, thus making the reverse lookup possible with the statement `state.place_set.all()`. 
On the contrary, you don't have any foreign key in your `Restaurant` model that points back to `State`, hence you won't be able to run the reverse lookup.

You should add a foreign key in `Restaurant` pointing to `Place` so you would be able to fetch places from states, then restaurants from places. Or probably, even better, a many 2 many relationship in `Place` that points to `Restaurant`, this way the reverse lookup from `State` would be a lot easier.

Be careful though because these kind of queries tend to be very expensive and you might need to jiggle how you fetch things by using the [select_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) and [prefetch_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) statements

Comment: thanks for the reply, I thought given I had implemented multi-table inheritance and could `Restaurant.state` that I would also be able to `state.restaurant_set.all()`. it would be a little annoying to have to move the ForeignKey('State')'s into each subclass....