# How to provide a queryset field for a subclass of a one-to-many relation in Django?

Tags: python, django

How can I provide a queryset field for a subclass of a one-to-many relation in Django?

Example:

```
class Concept(models.Model):
    ...


class StudyResource(models.Model):
    concept = models.ForeignKey(Concept, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ...


class VideoStudyResource(StudyResource):
    ...
```

Django provides:

```
concept.studyresource_set.all()
```

how can I also provide:

```
concept.videostudyresource_set.all()
```

Appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- To handle `One-To-Many` relationships in Django you need to use `ForeignKey`.
- [From this:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34238855/django-following-relationship-backwards-to-subclass-in-multi-table-inheritance) You can't follow the `ForeignKey` backwards from `Concept` to `VideoStudyResource`.

Comment: Thanks, I looked all over before posting to see if this question had already been asked and didn't find anything, but the link you referenced to another question does capture a similar issue well enough. Ended up using the solution suggested in the link, but it needs to be implemented carefully with apps.get_model() to avoid circular imports and seemed like a cleaner solution may have been possible.